# Select rows from a dataframe based on a pattern formed by consecutive values in a column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm average at R, and I would like some help with the following operation.

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
    >df
    ID   Label
    P1   M
    P1   S
    P2   M
    P2   M
    P2   S
    P3   M
    P3   S
    P3   M
    P4   S
    P4   M
    P5   M
    P5   M
    P5   S
```

I want to be able to select rows that occur in a particular sequence of the variable `Label` with respect to each ID.

For a pattern `"MS"`, the expected output would be

```
    ID   Label
    P1   M
    P1   S
    P2   M
    P2   S
    P3   M
    P3   S
```

and for a pattern `"MMS"`, the expected output would be

```
    ID   Label
    P2   M
    P2   M
    P2   S
    P5   M
    P5   M
    P5   S
```

and for pattern `"SM"`, the expected output is:

```
    ID   Label
    P3   S
    P3   M
    P4   S
    P4   M
```

Please consider the fact that the data I am working on has a lot of rows and the solution I need to build needs to work for patterns of arbitrary lengths. (ex. "MSS", "SM", "MMSSMS", etc). I humbly request for your assistance.

Edit: I have updated this question (the example dataframe and the output example of pattern `"MMS"`. I want to add that I want the pattern matching to happen after grouping the data using `ID` variable so that patterns can be found in the groups of data grouped by `ID`. Sorry for not being clear the first time.

Final Edit: Answers from @akrun, @boski, and @tmfmnk are working for me. @boski's and @akrun's solutions were faster in execution time (~2-10 seconds on 400k rows of data) compared to @tmfmnk's solution (~29 seconds on 400k rows of data). I advise the reader to refer all three of these solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `gregexpr()`. First paste all labels and find the start position of the pattern you are looking for.

```
> df
   ID Label
1  P1     M
2  P1     S
3  P2     M
4  P2     M
5  P2     S
6  P3     M
7  P3     S
8  P3     S
9  P4     S
10 P4     M
11 P5     M
12 P5     M
13 P5     S
```

**Edit**

My previous solution did not retrieve the whole pattern (just the start).

```
pattern="SM"
starts=gregexpr(pattern=pattern,paste(df$Label,collapse=""))[[1]]
positions=as.vector(sapply(starts,function(x){ 
  s=seq(x,x+nchar(pattern)-1)
  if (all(df$ID[s]==df$ID[x])){
    return(s)
  } else {return(rep(NA,nchar(pattern)))}
  }))
positions=positions[which(!is.na(positions))]

df[positions,]
df[positions,]
   ID Label
1  P1     M
2  P1     S
4  P2     M
5  P2     S
6  P3     M
7  P3     S
12 P5     M
13 P5     S

pattern="MMS"
   ID Label
3  P2     M
4  P2     M
5  P2     S
11 P5     M
12 P5     M
13 P5     S

pattern="SM"
   ID Label
9  P4     S
10 P4     M
```

Comment: Hey boski! Thanks for the answer, but the values that you've taken for the ID variable are wrong. Do have a look at it.

Comment: hey, I updated the answer to return the whole pattern and also made the labels same as yours.

Comment: Hey! Thanks again. Your answer is pretty close. I am sorry that I wasn't clear in my ask. I have edited my question. I want to find these patterns after grouping the data by ID. I have added one more example to make my ask clear.

Comment: I don't think I get what you are saying.. I get the exact same ouptut as your examples. I have updated with your new addition. **EDIT** ok I see now

Comment: it works now. It checks that all ids are equal before returning positions.

Comment: It works! Thanks! 
EDIT: I need to test the speed of execution of this snippet of code on my 400k row dataset. Will let you know the result.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to compare the `lead` values and get the index grouped by 'ID'

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- unique(setDT(df)[, lapply(which(Reduce(`&`, 
  Map(`==`, shift(Label, n = 0:2, type = "lead"), c("M", "M", "S")))), 
       function(i) .I[i:(i+2)]) , by = ID]$V1)
df[i1]
#    ID Label
#1: P2     M
#2: P2     M
#3: P2     S
#4: P5     M
#5: P5     M
#6: P5     S
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c("P1", "P1", "P2", "P2", "P2", "P3", "P3", 
"P3", "P4", "P4", "P5", "P5", "P5"), Label = c("M", "S", "M", 
"M", "S", "M", "S", "M", "S", "M", "M", "M", "S")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
```

Comment: Looks like this solution needs the length of the pattern entered. I would need to try this on my data (approx. 400k rows) and let you know how it performs.

Comment: I have edited the question. Before pattern matching, I want to group the data by ID and do this pattern matching on the individual groups and make the subset.

Comment: @SJEROMEGIDEON. In that case, you need to specify the `by = ID]`

Comment: Thanks akrun! Would you edit the answer with the same change? I think it would be useful for other. :D EDIT: adding `by = ID]` is giving wrong result.

Comment: Thanks! It works. Just have to modify the `0:2` and `i+2` parts according to the length of the pattern. I'll try this snippet on my 400k row dataset and let you know the result tomorrow.

Comment: Is there a Python equivalent to this solution that you know of?  I have a similar issue but using python.

Comment: @JakeP when you say equivalent, the syntax would be different because here we are using `data.table`, whereas in python, you may have to use `pandas`

Comment: @akrun you are correct, poor choice of wording on my part.  Do you know or have an idea of the python syntax for a task like this?

Answer (score 1):

One base solution for the original question could be:

```
nchar <- nchar("MS")
x <- grepRaw("MS", paste(df$Label, collapse = ""), all = TRUE)
y <- rep(x, each = nchar) + 0:(nchar - 1)

df[1:nrow(df) %in% y, ]

  ID Label
1 P1     M
2 P1     S
4 P2     M
5 P2     S
6 P3     M
7 P3     S

nchar <- nchar("SM")
x <- grepRaw("SM", paste(df$Label, collapse = ""), all = TRUE)
y <- rep(x, each = nchar) + 0:(nchar - 1)

df[1:nrow(df) %in% y, ]

   ID Label
2  P1     S
3  P2     M
5  P2     S
6  P3     M
9  P4     S
10 P4     M
```

Or written in a `dplyr` form:

```
nchar <- nchar("MS")
df %>%
 filter(row_number() %in% c(rep(grepRaw("MS", paste(Label, collapse = ""), all = TRUE), 
            each = nchar) + 0:(nchar - 1)))

   ID Label
1  P1     M
2  P1     S
3  P2     M
4  P2     S
5  P3     M
6  P3     S
7  P3     M
8  P4     S
9  P5     M
10 P5     S
```

Also addressing the edit of the question:

```
nchar <- nchar("MS")
df %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 filter(row_number() %in% c(rep(grepRaw("MS", paste(Label, collapse = ""), all = TRUE), 
            each = nchar) + 0:(nchar - 1)))

  ID    Label
  <fct> <fct>
1 P1    M    
2 P1    S    
3 P2    M    
4 P2    S    
5 P3    M    
6 P3    S    
7 P5    M    
8 P5    S
```